# OpenCv_ unhandle exception in load image with opencv2

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I installed OpenCV 2.4.10 and configured it to my Visual Studio 2010. And even I run below code in opencv(c)

My code in opencv:

```
#include "opencv\highgui.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv)

{
IplImage* img =cvLoadImage("d:\\1.jpg",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    cvNamedWindow("example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    cvShowImage("Example1", img);

    cvWaitKey(0);

    cvReleaseImage(&img);

    cvDestroyWindow("Exame1");
}
```

and it works but when I try to use the code given here,with opencv2(c++) but it gives an error (break)

My code in opencv2:

```
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
int main()

{
    Mat image = imread("d:\\1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    namedWindow("test", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    imshow("test", image);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Error(break):

> Unhandled exception at 0x7624c41f (KernelBase.dll) in o.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0035f63c..

Why is this error just in opencv2?!

I want to work with opencv2

Answer (score 0):

You will have to verify that you are building in debug/release mode based on the build information of the opencv .dll files you are using.

Comment: I built in debug, but in release my error is diffrence: >The program can't start beacuse opencv_highgui2410.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.......                                                Please help me @mike1821

Comment: You need to locate the opencv_highgui2410.dll inside the opencv installation directory and copy it in the folder that .exe file of your application is located.